# Mysql taking long time to insert and update Yii Framework

Tags: php, mysql, yii2

want to insert or update nearly 10000 records. It takes too long to insert in the for loop. Trying for the aternative way it only inserts the values but on duplicate_key entry shows the errors.

```
  $var=0;

  if($method == 1)
  {  

// $sql5 is the current way trying but shows error

  $sql5='insert into stu_regnum_hall(hall_name,row,column,register_number,subject_code,exam_date,session,unique_key) values';
for ($i = 0; $i <=$arr_length; $i++)
{
for ($j = 1; $j <= 5; $j++)
{
for($k=0;$k<=4;$k++)
{
if(isset($show[$var+$k]))
{
if($k==0)
{
$hall_name=$arr1[$i];
$row=$j;
}
$column=$k+1;
$reg_num=$show[$var+$k];
$sub_code=$newArr12[$var+$k];
$unique_key=$reg_num.$date.$session;

//current way to insert This is taking too long time to store nearly 10000 records                                                                                

Yii::$app->db->createCommand('insert into stu_regnum_hall(hall_name,row,column,register_number,subject_code,exam_date,session,unique_key) values ("'.$hall_name.'","'.$row.'","'.$column.'","'.$reg_num.'","'.$sub_code.'","'.$date.'","'.$session.'","'.$unique_key.'") ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE hall_name ="'.$hall_name.'",row="'.$row.'",column="'.$column.'",register_number="'.$reg_num.'",subject_code="'.$sub_code.'",exam_date="'.$date.'",session="'.$session.'",unique_key="'.$unique_key.'"')->query();                               

//concatenation of $sql5 
$sql5.='("'.$hall_name.'","'.$row.'","'.$column.'","'.$reg_num.'","'.$sub_code.'","'.$date.'","'.$session.'","'.$unique_key.'") ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE hall_name= "'.$hall_name.'",row="'.$row.'",column="'.$column.'",register_number="'.$reg_num.'",subject_code="'.$sub_code.'",exam_date="'.$date.'",session="'.$session.'",unique_ key="'.$unique_key.'",';   
   }
else
{
break;
}
}
$var=$var+5;
 }
}

$sql5.='("");';

   // This is the required answer but getting   error                                                                                                      
    Yii::$app->db->createCommand($sql5)->query();
    }
```

the $sql5 query should work in this

Comment: how long is to long?

Comment: nearly 5 minutes for 10000 records.  everytime insert query is executing in for loop. Thats the reason

Comment: since your just filling it with automated data, its going to be a one of job speed should not be an issue

Comment: This seems to be way too low-level a way to do it, and also very inefficient because there's a new statement for each row. Don't forget to use [placeholder values](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-security-best-practices.html) which will allow you to recycle the query for multiple rows, plus **properly escape things**. If you have tons and tons of data to load, never underestimate how quick `LOAD DATA INFILE` with a CSV source can be.

Comment: I just tried to make insert query as common and concatinate the values  in for loop. it works fast after i adding the  the update  entry only it showing  errors

Comment: It's slow because you're inserting one row at a time, with a SQL query executed for each row. Instead of doing that, why not build a single SQL query to insert all the values, and then execute that.

Comment: ya i have tried see the variable ($sql5) on the code.  It works only insert values while entering the update query it shows the error how to loop the duplcate entry also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `Yii2 batchInsert` with a little custom use `INSERT IGNORE`, `REPLACE` or `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`. It will insert very fast.

```
$sql = Yii::$app->db->queryBuilder->batchInsert('your_table_name', ['column1', 'column2','column3',...], $dataArray);
// For IGNORE on Duplicate
//$sql = 'INSERT IGNORE' . mb_substr($sql, strlen('INSERT'));
// For Replace on Duplicate
//$sql = 'REPLACE' . mb_substr($sql, strlen('INSERT'));
// For Update on Duplicate
$sql .= ' ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `column1` = VALUES(`column1`), `column2` = VALUES(`column2`), ...';

Yii::$app->db->createCommand($sql)->execute();
```

Refer: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-querybuilder.html#batchInsert()-detail

Comment: should not ignore should update the if unique key present

Comment: @SanthoshPrabu no problem